# "Consider Leaving a Comment" message

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes, popups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Please add a comment explaining..” still shows up when I add a comment and then downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78163/please-add-a-comment-explaining-still-shows-up-when-i-add-a-comment-and-then)

Just a minor nitpick on something I've noticed a few times:

As many of you know, when you downvote a question/answer, it gives you a message prompting you to leave a comment about why you did.

This is all well and good, except that I tend to write a comment first, and then down vote later if there's no improvement/response.    The message still prompts you to leave a comment, even though you already have added one.

I know it's really minor, but it's just a little oddity that I noticed.   It'd be nicer if it only gave the prompt when you actually hadn't commented, since the big dark red box (on meta anyway), always catches me as a "problem".

Comment: Nice to see this was closed as "exact duplicate" of a question that was opened 2 years AFTER this one...

Comment: it really doesn't matter on Meta which one is closed. However, the other one has the status-completed on it, which is probably why it's the canonical version. Also, for anyone flagging the other one as a duplicate of this one, well, it doesn't make sense to close that one as a dup of this one if this one is already closed as a dup of another one. That sort of doesn't make a lot of sense and is circular....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree.

I've had similar thoughts but considered it too minor to post a question on.  Trivial, yes.  But that box is just a hair too invasive.

A variation:  *If one up votes someone else's comment, then don't show the box.*  The implication being that you are supporting someone else's comment on why there was a down vote and there is no need to bug folks about it.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, definitely minor, but I imagine it should not be terribly hard to do a quick query of the comments on that question and see if any were left by you when a downvote occurs.

Comment: Or simply remove the box if you have written *any* comment on that answer.