# "Please add a comment explaining.." still shows up when I add a comment and then downvote

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, down-votes

If I downvote, I always get the "please add a comment explaining why blah blah" text. I think this is a bug because many times I will comment and then downvote. So the text is telling me to do what I just did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After tonight's build, we'll be suppressing the "please consider adding a comment" popup **if you have already commented** on the post you're downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

It does not say "please add", it says "remember you can."

And the intent here is just as a reminder, it does not know or care if you actually left a comment.

This reminder goes away at 1k or 2k rep as I recall, so.. get more rep! :)

Comment: It's still annoying :)

Comment: The rep requirement does not appear to be relaxed on the beta sites (as so many of them were.) I have ~1300 rep on the sqa beta, and it still appears. I, too, find it annoying. It seems silly to remind someone they can do something that they have already done. I feel this is more `status-easiertocode` than `status-bydesign` (which is, in my opinion, still a completely valid reason, as you must always weigh practical cost against the endless list of incoming feature requests, but it's still an important subset of 'by design.')

Comment: It's super annoying to comment, downvote, and then be asked to comment. The explanation that it "doesn't know" if you left a comment is simply elaborating on the bug report. It should know. When I upvote answers it knows if I've been voting on questions. Heck, when I upvote a comment it knows I upvoted another comment less than 5 seconds ago. So please, can it deign to know that I commented right before I downvoted? I would really like that.

Comment: @kate good point, we should probably check in that case. Will see if we can add that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual behavior i have grown in habit of seeing.

Yeah This is a bug which is caused by the feature of suggesting the user to Add a comment. I think the down vote event is not bound with comments and so it shows.

Flowing are my thoughts on this:

- I believe it is always a good thing to show the user to add a comment because it could be that what user commented about could be an answer to someone Else's comment or to ask a question from the OP. So the computer has no idea weather the comment was for down-vote or some usual chatter with the OP. So it dosent seem like it could be implemented perfectly.
- If the user is shown that always it will force the user to rethink his action and see it was worth down-vote and he should give a comment explaining the cause for down-vote.
- Also if user has already mentioned the reason in comment that notification will force him to check whether his comment for cause is appropriate.

Overall it will improve the quality of comments and Justify the down-votes.

Comment: Well, I'd say all your points are valid, except for the "please comment" box goes away after reaching a certain amount of reputation. So your points are moot in my opinion

Comment: Umm i havent seen that  behavior with certain amount yet...but as i said it is a bug as it looks like  the Notification feature is not bound to comment system..