# Why does community ask me to leave a comment when I already have?

Tags: bug, comments, vote-to-close

When closing a question (as a moderator) I leave a comment explaining why, and pointing the OP to the faq, unless this has already been done.

What seems a little odd is when community raises the following flag:

> Please explain the nature of this closed question via a comment – Community

Is it just an automated script that doesn't check to see if you have left a comment? If so then I'm happy to ignore it, but wouldn't it be useful if it checked?

This is possibly related to: ["Please add a comment explaining.." still shows up when I add a comment and then downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78163/154443) but is in different circumstances.

Comment: I think it checks only for diamond comments. If there are comments from regular users that sufficiently explain the closure, I'd upvote them, dismiss the flag and move on... Also, this is a beta only flag.

Comment: C'mon! Decline Community flags and make its *flag-weight* get to hellban!

Comment: Does Community *have* flag weight? :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio It does. Check its profile on a site you're a moderator and you'll see how many helpful and unhelpful flags it has.

Comment: @yannis - normally I just accept the flag. But **this** time I declined and left a comment :-)

Comment: I think this happens because you close, then comment, and commenting just doesn't dismiss the flag

Comment: I can't remember the order this time round. Usually I think I comment first and then close. I think. Will check next time :-)

Comment: Oh yes, if you first closed and then commented, the flag has already been raised (although it might take a min or so to appear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked and @Yannis and @Ben's comments are correct.

- If you comment then close, the flag should not be raised
- If you close and then comment the flag is raised as you close, even if you comment before this becomes evident

Makes perfect sense, and this means the correct activity order when a mod closes is to ensure that there is a comment explaining the close before clicking the close button. Which is probably a good thing anyway, as if the OP sees the close notification and goes to check the question, they may get there before any explanation is given and not understand.

Comment: Since I'm redoing flagging right now, would you like it if, in the case of your second bullet point, the flag is automatically cleared?

Comment: @Jarrod - if that is an easy fix then it would be lovely,but if not, now I know the correct order it is no longer a problem to me.